# EnumDataType() attribute validation error message not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, asp.net-core-2.0, data-annotations

In my .net core 2.0 Web API I am using EnumDataType() validation attribute on my model property. When the validation fails the custom error message is empty. I am not sure why it is happening -

```
[EnumDataType(typeof(MyEnum), ErrorMessage = "Custom Error Message")]
public MyEnum MyEnumProp {get; set;}
```

I checked the other properties where I have [Required], [MinLength] and all are generating custom error messages. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 17):

It's a frequent confusion between errors detected during deserialization and validation stages.

Say you have the following `enum`:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    None,
    Value1,
    Value2
}
```

and the following model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(MyEnum), ErrorMessage = "Custom Error Message")]
    public MyEnum MyEnumProp { get; set; }
}
```

When you post the data:

```
{
  "Id": 123,
  "MyEnumProp": "UnexistingEnumValue"
}
```

the error will happen during deserialization stage (in Json.NET for this case). Deserializer just has no way to convert string `"UnexistingEnumValue"` to some of values from `MyEnum`.
In this case deserializer will register following model binding error: `Requested value 'UnexistingEnumValue' was not found`.

`ModelState.IsValid` will be set to `false`, however value of `MyEnumProp` will be left at its default value of `MyEnum.None`. Validation performed by `EnumDataType` attribute will not detect any error, because `MyEnum.None` is a valid value for `MyEnum`. That is why you will not see `"Custom Error Message"` in `ModelState` errors.

Now if you post the following data:

```
{
  "Id": 123,
  "MyEnumProp": 5
}
```

No error will happen during deserialization stage, because following assignment is pretty legal even if it does not make much sense:

```
MyEnum v = (MyEnum)5;
```

So deserializer will not detect any errors. However now `EnumDataType` validation comes into play. And it detects that `5` is not a valid value for `MyEnum`. `ModelState.IsValid` is set to `false` and the error message specified in `EnumDataType.ErrorMessage` is registered (`"Custom Error Message"`).

If you want to have the same custom message for both deserialization and validation errors, you should go up to the level of deserializer (Json.NET) and use its extensibility points for this purpose.

Comment: thanks for putting this down. However, can you please help in - how to go up to the level of deserializer?

Comment: I haven't did it before that's why I can't provide you a sample code. Also I'm not a fan of such approach and will not add it to my own projects. The problem with such customization is that it should be performed for any supported media formatter. Say you find a way to do it for JSON, but what about XML format which also could be used for posting data to your API? As result you should add too much customization code without adding visible value.

Comment: Also seems like ASP.NET Core team realized the problem we are discussing. Check [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4862), [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4607), [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6789) and [this commit](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/pull/7015/commits/06153a98bce6260699a5c43bbbaf401f8b44cd5f#diff-c5593231b956b26d4dd4dc1cd82fdc76). So may be you should wait for ASP.NET Core 2.1 (or play with preview version) and check whether these changes got to it.

Answer (score 0):

Change to int the property MyEnumProp

```
public class TestModel

    {
        [Required]
        public int? Id { get; set; }
    
        [EnumDataType(typeof(MyEnum), ErrorMessage = "Custom Error Message")]
        public int MyEnumProp { get; set; }
    }
```