# Ignore nulls in EnumDataType data annotation attribute

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I have a model with a nullable enum and an API layer. In the API layer, I get the model and checking its state. When I send a null value in this enum I get an error message from the model state because the enum cannot be null. Is it possible to change the attribute so that it will ignore and not add error message in case of null?

This is my code:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [EnumDataType(typeof(MyEnum?))]
    public MyEnum? MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

And this the API layer:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<int> Post(MyModel myModel)
{
    Validate(myModel);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Stop the process and return a message...
    }

    //Continue with the process.
    //Call the BL, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should change the type passed to `EnumDataType` attribute from `MyEnum?` to `MyEnum`. `EnumDataType` expects `enum` type but `MyEnum?` is actually `Nullable<MyEnum>` which will cause `InvalidOperationException`.

Then following JSON posted in request body should be correctly deserialized to the model:

```
{
  "MyEnum": null
}
```

After deserialization by JSON.NET, `MyModel.MyEnum` property will be set to `null`. `EnumDataType` will not perform any validation for `null` value and you get valid model.

> When I send a null value in this enum I get an error message from the
>   model state because the enum cannot be null.

The most probable reason is that you send `null` value as a string:

```
{
  "MyEnum": "null"
}
```

Such JSON will cause deserialization error (inside JSON.NET), because deserializer does not know how to convert string `"null"` to `MyEnum`. This is not an error produced by validation attribute, because any validation is executed only if deserilization completes successfully. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49704850/5740031) for more details about model deserialization and validation stages.

Comment: This is interesting. I want to elaborate on the nullable enum. Say my model is expected to accept either `null` or correct value of Enum, e.g. 1,2,3. 

On the deserialization it works with null(does not throw exception). But on Validation it throws `InvalidOperationException` - as you mentioned. 

How to handle such case?