# Unable to customise ErrorMessage of EnumDataType attribute

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have the following defined in a DTO:

```
[EnumDataType(typeof(Role), ErrorMessage = "The role must be one of; ...")]
public Role Role { get; set; }
```

My `Role` `enum` has the `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]` annotation.

When making a call to me endpoint, if I don't provide the `role` property in the JSON I get the error message 'The role must be one of; ...'. However, if I provide a `role` that is not a valid `Role` `enum` I don't get that message but instead I get:

```
"errors": [
  "input": [
    "The input field is required."
    ],
    "$.role": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to Role. Path $.role | LineNumber: 3 | BytePosition: 16."
    ]
  ]
]
```

**Note:** In the above that `input` refers to the name of my endpoint action parameter.

I am confused as to why this works when I don't provide anything but doesn't when I do but with an invalid `enum`. I understand what the error is telling me (it can't convert the value I am sending, presumably because it doesn't exist as an `enum` value?) but how do I return **my** error message in instances the value is invalid?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EnumDataType() attribute validation error message not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691685/enumdatatype-attribute-validation-error-message-not-displaying)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Kind of? It is informative in the sense I now understand it is not a validation but a deserialization issue. I'm still unclear as to how to resolve it though. Looking at the links provided by [CodeFuller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5740031/codefuller) suggests this `undefined enum` issue has been resolved but that doesn't appear to be the case?